# How do you iterate through a list in c# using mustache and get each value in a placeholder

Tags: c#, html, mustache

I am using mustache# for .Net and to help me get values into a html template for an email application.  I am able to get mustache placeholders to store single values but having issues iterating through a a list and saving the values in a placeholder.

My example list in the code I provide below is a simple string List with 2 elements. When the email sends and the html template is attached All I am getting for this is System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String] twice.
I understand why its showing up twice because of there being 2 elements in the list.  I just don't know how to have it show each value instead.

```
List<string> namelist = new List<string>();
namelist.Add("Val");
namelist.Add("Jeff");

const string names = "{{#each name}} <h2> Hello, {{name}}</h2> {{/each}}";

HtmlFormatCompiler compilers = new HtmlFormatCompiler();

Generator generator = compilers.Compile(names);

string result = generator.Render(new
{
     name = namelist

});


string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
("~/Views/Shared/_HpNotificationEmailTemplate.cshtml"));

string emailBody = string.Format(template,result);
```

I am expecting it to show the values  Val and Jeff but I am just getting System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String] twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know but the the Mustache for C# template syntax does not seem to be the same as that used in javascript. It probably an old implementation, anyway, the solution is to use {{this}} instead of {{name}}

```
 List<string> namelist = new List<string>();
 namelist.Add("Val");
 namelist.Add("Jeff");

 const string names = "{{#each name}} <h2> Hello, {{this}}</h2> {{/each}}";
 HtmlFormatCompiler compilers = new HtmlFormatCompiler();

 Generator generator = compilers.Compile(names);

 string result = generator.Render(new
 {
    name = namelist
 });
```

Comment: awesome this works! Now if  i added a second list  ex. 
List<string> namelist2 = new List<string>();
namelist.Add("Nick");
namelist.Add("Patrick");

and in string results i added name2 = namelist2  is there a way to use this for both in const string names = "{{#each name}} <h2> Hello, {{this}}</h2> {{/each}}";? so for example it says hello Val, hi Nick  @user2818985